# iOS app stalls phone when on a weak Wi-Fi signal

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I've recently noticed a bug on the Stack Exchange iOS app. When I open the Stack Exchange app on a weak Wi-Fi signal, it hangs on the blue load screen as it launches and either crashes the app or the entire phone lags and doesn't respond for about a minute.

I'm running iOS 8.4.1, I have the most up-to-date version of the app, and by a 'weak' Wi-Fi signal I mean two out of four bars of strength.

Comment: Hmm... the app shouldn't freeze on the home screen when there's a poor connection.  With 100% data loss or airplane mode I'm still able to load and look at cached favorite questions.  Can you provide more context about what state the app is in when launching (where did you leave off?) and what device you have?

Comment: @BrianNickel when I have *no* connection, it'll load fine like you say; it's where I have a poor wifi connection that it fails.  In terms of state, it's been anything, whether it be looking at a particular question or just looking through the active question; I haven't been able to identify anything particularly different there.  I'm using an iPhone 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.3.

I believe you're seeing the same issue as [iOS app crashes on startup under slow internet connections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270802/ios-app-crashes-on-startup-under-slow-internet-connections).  The app was blocking on the site list because the feed had a site it didn't recognize.